# Change state in localstorage

Tags: javascript

I have problem with changing data in localstorage. I am making cart and i have a lot of products. After clicking "add to cart" in product page, data checks if localstorage already has this product, so if it is true, product is not adding it just changes count state. All is working until the moment when i am adding another product. After this, when i want so add product that is already in localstorage it has to change count state, but it adds one more time this product. Why?
Can you help me please.

```
0: {titleProduct: "first", productPrice: "15", count: 2}
1: {titleProduct: "second"", productPrice: "9", count: 3}
2: {titleProduct: "first", productPrice: "15", count: "1"}
```

but it should look like this

```
0: {titleProduct: "first", productPrice: "15", count: 3}
1: {titleProduct: "second"", productPrice: "9", count: 3}
```

Code:

```js
  const rawData = localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]";
const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
var setData;

data.filter(titleNow => {
  if (titleNow.titleProduct == titleProduct) {
  setData = true;
  }
  else {
    setData = false;
  }
});


  if (setData) {
   data.filter(item => {
    item.titleProduct == titleProduct ? item.count = parseInt(item.count)+Number(dataCart.innerHTML) : "";
})
  } else {


    data.push({titleProduct, productPrice, count: dataCart.innerHTML});
   

  }

  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I assume those extra quotes in the JSON fragments are typos? If so, please correct

Comment: You are incrementing count inside filter. filter essentially returns an array. You might want to use array reduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` is not the right function to use here. Use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Problem in your code is that `setData` variable is set depending on whether the last product's title is equal to `titleProduct` or not. If it is, `setData` will be set to true otherwise it will be false. So if you had tried to add the third product with the title `second`, your code would have worked.

```
const product = data.find(prod => prod.titleProduct === titleProduct);

if (prod) {
   prod.count++;
} else {
   data.push({titleProduct, productPrice, count: dataCart.innerHTML});
}

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this

```
const updatedCart = data.map(item => {
    if(titleProduct === item.titleProduct){
        return {
            ...item,
            count: dataCart.innerHTML
        }
    }
    else{
        return item
    }
})

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(updatedCart));
```

Iterates over data and changes the count for dataCart.innerHTML if titleProduct concurs with the iteratee